# ORA-00904: "P_YEARS": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

ORA-00904: "P_YEARS": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 42

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION experience(p_years IN OUT NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER IS V_YEARS NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT (SYSDATE - HIRE_DATE)/365
INTO V_YEARS
FROM EMPLOYEES;
p_years := v_years;
RETURN (p_years);
END experience;
```

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, experience(p_years)
FROM   employees
WHERE  department_id= 50;
```

Comment: @AlexPoole yeah, sorry, that wasn't right error, i edited my problem
And thats my whole anonymous block, this code should work, and i am new at pl/sql

Comment: You don't have an anonymous block; you have a function, and a plain SQL statement. Which is fine (if the function worked) except the assignment wanted a block - with declare/begin/end, and then presumably a cursor and 'printing that data' via `dbms_output`. Anyway, in your current plain SQL statement, `p_years` doesn't exist - it isn't a column in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things are incorrect.  No need for an in/out parameter *and* a return from a function.  Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION experience(P_HireDate IN  DATE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
   return (SYSDATE - P_HIREDATE) / 365;
END experience;

SELECT first_name, last_name, experience(hire_date)
FROM   employees
WHERE  department_id= 50;
```

Note that the result of subtracting two dates is in units of days.

Comment: yeahh, thank you man, yeah i used "extract year"